# Web api route values is empty on action executes filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am using a custom action filter on my controller action.

My controller action is like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("listener")]   
    [MyAttr]     
    public IHttpActionResult Listener([FromBody]Parameters request)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
```

I want to access `Route("listener")` values from action filter.

```
public class MyAttr: ActionFilterAttribute
{        
    public async override Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
         var route = actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.RequestContext.RouteData;       
    }
}
```

But RouteData values collection has no items. How can access route value?

My configuration is like this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Its not route data, route data can only be supplied in the URL and your method has data supplied in the http body.

Comment: How can I access "listener" of Route attribute parameter?

Comment: @bookmarker
Do you want to access the URI the request is coming to?

Comment: You could access its attributes, try `actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes<Route>()`

Comment: and then you can access its `Template` property https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.routeattribute.template(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Http.RouteAttribute.Template

Answer (score 0):

Please add **/{action}** in your **WebApiConfig.cs** file.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**api/ControllerName/Listener** the link will to be that.